# A word in print, is for generations after generations. - source of the Rebbe Rayatz

Tags: sources-mekorot, chabad, quotations

The Lubavitcher Rebbe, in one of his letters (letter no. 184, dated from 7 Shvat, 5705), cites the Rebbe Rayatz (The Tzemach Tzedek) and says:

> A word spoken is public knowledge; in writing, it is for the entire world, and in print, it is for generations after generations.’”

The Rebbe quotes the Tzemach Tzedek from Igros Kodesh (אגרות קודש) of the Rebbe Rayatz, Vol. II, Letter No. 558

Does anyone know where to find this? I could not find it unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source can be find on Hebrewbooks [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31602&st=&pgnum=448&hilite=) (3rd paragraph)

[image]

> So I received from our master our teacher, the holy Rabbi, the Tzemach Tzedek, his righteous and holy memory should be as a blessing for life in the next world. He once said that a Jew when he speaks, needs to know the next word in his speech as it is public. And a word that is written is before the world. And word in print is for generations. And he concluded his words - if our Sages were saying about our Rabbis of blessed memory, "be cautious about your words", then how much more so the average person.

Comment: Thanks Dov! As always!

Comment: Always happy to help!

Comment: If you could add a translation, that would also be very helpful :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Shmuel - done :-)

Comment: I think "U'Befrat Chulu" is referring to less than a benoni

Answer (score 3):

[image: Igrot Kodesh_Rayatz_Vol2]

[image: second page]
This is the actual letter published from volume 2 that is quoted.

Comment: @Yaakov - I have a Hebrewbook link with this edition in the answer....

Comment: I didn’t even look at answers when I saw the question. I just grabbed that volume off the shelf. But you got the full credit for your answer.

Comment: Thanks @YaacovDeane

Comment: @Shmuel Happy to help! Have a great Elul.